# Open and run file using path

Tags: java, file

I have the code below to get the file name and location of a file in a directory.

How can I use the File class to open this file? (eg: if its art.jpeg, I want to open the file with the default jpeg viewer.)

```
File root = new File( path );
File[] list = root.listFiles();

 for ( File f : list ) {
                if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
                    walk( f.getAbsolutePath() );
                    System.out.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
                    //OPEN FILE HERE
                }
 }
```

Comment: Any specific operating system or os-independent?

Comment: @AleksG Windows only would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have said to use something like (Where `file` is actually `f` for you):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file)
```

See the documentation here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Desktop.open()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))

Launches the associated application to open the file.

> Supported operations include:

- launching the user-default browser to show a specified URI;
- launching the user-default mail client with an optional mailto URI;
- launching a registered application to open, edit or print a specified
  file.

Comment: Please provide a very simple example. Thanks!